# R+reprex: create a reproducible example when rendering a R markdown file

Tags: r, r-markdown, reprex

I cannot give an example, otherwise I would not ask this question at all.
I love the reprex package for R. However, sometimes I write some simple R markdown code with I process with rmarkdown::render(). Is there a way I can use the reprex package on an R markdown file to generate a reproducible example which is easy to post, for instance, on this site?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [`reprex_render`](https://reprex.tidyverse.org/reference/reprex_render.html) function from `reprex` package to render `.R` or `.Rmd` files.

> This is a wrapper around rmarkdown::render() that enforces the
> "reprex" mentality.

Here is a reproducible example:

```
reprex::reprex_render(input = "reprex_test.Rmd")
```

Output viewer:

[image]

---

Example Rmarkdown file called `reprex_test.Rmd`:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
date: "2024-02-22"
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document. You can embed an R code chunk like this:

```{r cars}
summary(cars)
```

## Including Plots

You can also embed plots, for example:

```{r pressure, echo=FALSE}
plot(pressure)
```

Note that the `echo = FALSE` parameter was added to the code chunk to prevent printing of the R code that generated the plot.
````

Comment: Thanks! Just one last question: on my linux box, the rendered document is not automatically copied to some clipboard (unlike the case of the reprex of an R code). How do I share the output of my rendered Rmd code as you did?